# How to create a sortby Expression<Func<TEntity,TResult>> when you don't know the sortby type at compile time

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, sorting, expression-trees

I'm using JqGrid in my asp.net 4.0 web app and I want implement column sorting. My issue is that the Get method in my repo class requires an Expression> type for the sort by parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> orderBy, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalNumberOfRecords, SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> list = null;
            int numberOfRecordsToSkip = CalculateNumberOfRecordsToSkip(pageIndex, pageSize);
            if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                list = GetQuery().Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip).Take(pageSize).AsEnumerable().ToList();            
            }
            else
            {
                list = GetQuery().Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(orderBy).Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip).Take(pageSize).AsEnumerable().ToList();
           }

            totalNumberOfRecords = GetQuery().Count(predicate);
            return list;
        }
```

How do I create that sort by expression when all I know is the type of the entity at compile time? I want to be able to sort the grid by any column (or entity property if you like).

The method that should create the sort by expression takes one parameter and that is the column name:

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> CreateOrderByExpression(string sortColumn)
{

 // I don't know the TOrderBy type before this method is called. I know the TEntity type  // so getting the type of the sortColumn is easy. 
// But how do I create the Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderBy>> from here ?

}
```

So the result from the method CreateOrderByExpression should be used as an parameter to the
Get method in my repo class.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DynamicLinq lib (1 .cs file actually):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I didn't check this one but I'm sure it worth a look: https://nuget.org/packages/DynamicLINQ

edit: examples for the Nugget package: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx
(looks really good and easy!)